Express with nunjuck templates throws ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT
I have Node.js project written in ESModule Typescript, using Express.js and Inversify. I'm looking to integrate Nunjucks as the templating engine although I get following error whenever i try to access endpoint rendering output using njk:
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:659:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/bailando/projects/learning-platform/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.contentType (/home/bailando/projects/learning-platform/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:624:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/bailando/projects/learning-platform/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:149:14)
    at done (/home/bailando/projects/learning-platform/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1045:10)
    at /home/bailando/projects/learning-platform/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:28:5
    at RawTask.call (/home/bailando/projects/learning-platform/node_modules/asap/asap.js:40:19)
    at flush (/home/bailando/projects/learning-platform/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}

This is my index.ts:
import 'dotenv/config';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import container from './ioc.config.js';
import nunjucks from 'nunjucks';
import { InversifyExpressServer } from 'inversify-express-utils';

const server = new InversifyExpressServer(container);

server.setConfig((app) => {
  nunjucks.configure('views', {
    autoescape: true,
    express: app
  });

  app.set('view engine', 'njk');
});

const app = server.build();

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on http://localhost:3000');
});

My home.controller.ts:
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { controller, httpGet } from 'inversify-express-utils';

@controller('/')
export class HomeController {
  constructor() {}

  @httpGet('/')
  public async getUsers(_: Request, res: Response) {
    res.render('home');
  }
}

And my home.njk for now is just plain text Hello world
Any tips on what might be going wrong? When I reconfigured the setup to use Pug, everything worked perfectly, so I’m wondering if there’s a compatibility issue between Express and Nunjucks, though I am almost sure I’ve used a similar setup successfully in the past. Similary when I return plain string in endpoint, everything works fine.

I've managed to find workaround. It renders correctly when I wrap res.render in a Promise and resolve with html string from callback:
@controller('/')
export class HomeController {
  @httpGet('/')
  public async showHome(@request() req: Request, @response() res: Response) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      res.render('home', (err, html) => {
        if (!err) resolve(html);

        reject(err);
      });
    });
  }
}

Although, I am still curious if it is possible to do this without any wrapper.
